# Fmincon / Multistart: Local minimum found, but one nonlinear constraint is violated

Tags: matlab

i am trying to find an optimal point with multistart / fmincon. Matlab finds a local minima, for which the following message is given in the output struct:

```
Local minimum found that satisfies the constraints.
Optimization completed because the objective function is non-decreasing in feasible directions, 
to within the value of the optimality tolerance,and constraints are satisfied to within the value of the 
constraint tolerance.<stopping criteria details>
Optimization completed: The relative first-order optimality measure, 7.337955e-07,
is less than options.OptimalityTolerance = 1.000000e-06, and the relative maximum constraintviolation, 7.082693e-07, is less than options.ConstraintTolerance = 1.000000e-06.
```

I have 13 nonlinear constraints, of which one is violated.

This is the constraint:

```
c(10) = abs(L_1 - (L_2 - L_3)) - 0.001;
```

I want to achieve:

```
abs(L_1 - (L_2 - L_3)) <= 0.001;
```

If i check this constraint by hand, I get

```
abs(L_1 - (L_2 - L_3)) = 0.0011;
```

which is larger than the desired value 0.001
The constraint tolerance in optimoptions is set to 1e-6 by default.
How can this happen? The output clearly says, that all the constraints are met, but in reality this one is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood what `fmincon` provides. Solutions are guaranteed to satisfy the bounds. There is no assurance that all constraints (linear or non-linear) will be satisfied.

I will admit that you have to read between the lines when looking at the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html).

> For the default 'interior-point' algorithm, fmincon sets components of x0 that violate the bounds lb ≤ x ≤ ub, or are equal to a bound, to the interior of the bound region. For the 'trust-region-reflective' algorithm, fmincon sets violating components to the interior of the bound region. For other algorithms, fmincon sets violating components to the closest bound. Components that respect the bounds are not changed. See Iterations Can Violate Constraints.

Comment: but why is one able to define nonlinear constraints if fmincon will violate them nonetheless? Also, why does matlab say that all constraints are satisfied?

Comment: If you can provide enough detail to recreate the solution on my end that would be ideal. `fmincon` will return and exit flag and a best feasible point output structure as well as other details that a worth inspection.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not give you a minimal example of the problem, because of the high complexity of my program. Matlab produces the exitflag 1. Maybe you could help me further by explaining why I might have misunderstood what fmincon does.

Comment: I want to add, that i use upper and lower bounds and nonlinear constraints. All other conditions for fmincon are set to [ ].